# FInd in array and output whole array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [feature class] => L 
        [feature code] => RGN 
        [country code] => ES 
        [admin1code] => 00 
        [admin2code] => CO 
        [geonameid] => 2521750 )

Array ( [feature class] => A 
        [feature code] => ADM1 
        [country code] => ES 
        [admin1code] => 51 
        [admin2code] => [geonameid] => 2593109 )

Array ( [feature class] => S 
        [feature code] => GDN 
        [country code] => ES 
        [admin1code] => 60 
        [admin2code] => A 
        [geonameid] => 10290879 )
```

Here are my 3 print_r arrays. How hot check which one has this: `[feature code] => ADM1` and then from that array output this : `[country code] => ES [admin1code] => 51`

P.S

Here is my array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [feature class] => L [feature code] => RGN [country code] => ES [admin1code] => 00 [admin2code] => CO [geonameid] => 2521750 ) [1] => Array ( [feature class] => A [feature code] => ADM1 [country code] => ES [admin1code] => 51 [admin2code] => [geonameid] => 2593109 ) [2] => Array ( [feature class] => S [feature code] => GDN [country code] => ES [admin1code] => 60 [admin2code] => A [geonameid] => 10290879 ) )
```

I did: `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`

Now how do I find which array has in it this: `[feature code] => ADM1` and output it's all data?

Comment: your requirement is not clear. Also let us know your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the 3 arrays are named as follows: $arr1, $arr2, and $arr3. Put them all into 1 array and loop through to check:

```
$all = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];
foreach ($all as $a) {
    if ($a['feature code'] === "ADM1") $result = $a;
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Glad I helped. :)

Comment: Buddy sorry to bother you again but it doesn't output the correct key or array!